# Unable to authenticate while pushing my code to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am encountering an issue while trying to push my code to my Bitbucket repository using `git push bitbucket <mybranch>` command.

After entering my password in the popup screen that appears on my VS Code interface (as shown in the attached picture), I keep receiving an error message stating

> remote: Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method.
> remote: If you are unsure of which login details or login method to use, visit:
> remote: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/log-into-or-connect-to-bitbucket-cloud/
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'myrepository'

I suspect that the issue may be related to the fact that I have enabled two-step authentication on my Bitbucket account. I checked out the documentation so I also tried to insert my private key instead of my password but I get the same result.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you've enabled multi-factor authentication, then you won't be able to use your regular username and password for Git operations. You have two options: disable MFA (a terrible, terrible, terrible idea), or switch your repos to use SSH instead.

Since you're using VS Code, and since you didn't mention which operating system you're on, you should be able to follow the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_ssh-tips for your repo. The SSH URL for your repo should be something like `git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo`, though VS Code might separate the username (`git`) and host (`bitbucket.org`) from the repository path (`owner/repo`).

If you'd prefer a command-line approach, then you can run `git remote set-url bitbucket git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo` instead.